# Css multiple images background. Can't make it work

Tags: html, css

I'm having a problem setting up div's background in 3 parts (I have a big shadow in 3 parts - top, mid (repeatable) and bottom). Unfortunately, they're a bit opaque so I can't have mid appear all the way from top to bottom... How can I set up background so the mid portion only appears between top and bot?

Current code that gives the problem:

```
background-image: url('shadow_top.png'), url('shadow_bot.png'), url('shadow_mid.png');
background-repeat: no-repeat, no-repeat, repeat-y;
background-position: center top, center bottom, center top;
```

Comment: does this help? background-position: top, bottom, center;

Comment: When having such a problem you should probably think if it is really necessary or not to use images as background. 99% of the time you are fine without them e.g. by using a css gradient or a box-shadow .

Comment: This may help:
http://css-tricks.com/stacking-order-of-multiple-backgrounds/

Comment: Can I somehow build 3-part gradient in CSS though? :/ Shadow basically looks like this: 

http://imgur.com/wnPasBR.png (sample image)

Comment: looks like a wide box-shadow with lots of spread to me. http://css3gen.com/box-shadow/

Comment: Mind blown! Spread with high blur does the trick. Thanks man!